# FV of an annuity-immediate

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

The question is "Find the FV of an annuity-immediate with payments of $50$ every $6$ months for $8$ years at a nominal rate of interest of $4\%$ compounded semiannually."

$p\times  s_{\overline{n}|i}$. When computing $i$, I would do $(1+0.04) = (1+ \frac{i^{(2)}}{2})^2$ and solve for $i^{(2)}$, but that is the wrong method since the given interest rate in the solution is $2\%$.

What would the correct set-up be to find the interest rate, and what is the intuition for getting it the right way vs. my approach?

Comment: Semi annual compounding means divide the rate by 2.  $(1+\frac {0.04}{2})^k$

Comment: What would k be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the cash flow occurs at the same interval as the compounding of interest, then the calculation is simple.  In this case, payments are made every 6 months--i.e., semiannually--and the nominal rate of interest also is specified as being compounded semiannually.  So, the effective semiannual rate of interest is simply half of the nominal rate; i.e., $$i^{(2)}/2 = 0.04/2 = 0.02$$ is the effective rate, and the desired future (or accumulated) value is $$50 s_{\overline{16}\rceil 0.02}.$$  The number of payments is simply $8$ years times $2$ payments per year.

The calculation is not so simple if the compounding period is not the same as the rate of cash flow; e.g., if the payments were to occur every month, rather than every six months, how would the accumulated value calculation change?  Here, we need the **monthly** effective rate of interest, not the semiannual rate.  The effective semiannual rate is $0.02$ as we said before, so in order to find the effective monthly rate, we need a rate $j$ such that $$(1+j)^6 = 1 + 0.02,$$ because we need to know what rate, if it were compounded over a $6$-month term, would be equivalent to ("effectively") the semiannual rate.

But what if the compounding frequencies are not integer multiples?  For example, what if the effective semiannual rate was still $0.02$, but the payments are made every $4$ months (i.e. $3$ times a year)?  Then we should consider the smallest period common to both compounding rates; i.e., $$1+i = \left(1 + \frac{i^{(2)}}{2}\right)^2 = (1.02)^2,$$ and then solve $$(1 + j)^3 = (1.02)^2,$$ which gives the effective $4$-month rate.

Answer (score 1):

$i^{(2)}=4\%$ so we have that the semiannual effective interest rate is $i_s=2\%$ and the number of payment is $n=2\times m=2\times 8=16$ where $m=8$ is the number of years, the payment is $p=50$.
So the future value is
$$
FV=p\times s_{\overline{n}|i_s}=p\times\frac{(1+i_s)^{16}-1}{i_s}=50\times\frac{(1.02)^{16}-1}{0.02}=931.96
$$

Observe that we have $(1+i_s)^2=\left(1+\frac{i^{(2)}}{2}\right)^2=1+i$ where $i$ is the effective annual interest rate and then
$$
FV=p\times s_{\overline{n}|i_s}=p\times\frac{(1+i_s)^{n}-1}{i_s}=p\times\frac{(1+i)^{m}-1}{i}\times \frac{i}{i_s}=p\times s_{\overline{m}|i}\times \frac{i}{i_s}
$$